# XOR comparison between two Conditions in JooQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

In my WHERE condition in PostgreSQL I have something in the following form:

`a != b`

where a and b are booleans.

However, JooQ decides that boolean is a `Condition` which only knows `or` and `and`. I can convert to DNF, but that greatly reduces readability (because then it becomes `(a and !b) or (!a and b)`).

Is there any other way to implement this use case?

## Example

Say I have the following SQL code:

```
WHERE (field_a IS NOT NULL) != (field_b IS NULL)
```

I would like to convert it to JooQ code similar to this:

```
where(DSL.field("field_a", Integer.class).isNotNull().notEq(DSL.field("field_b", Integer.class).isNull()))
```

I cannot, because `notEq` is not a method on the `Condition` class.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I could wrap the `Condition` as a `Field` using `DSL.field(Condition)`. The `Field` class does have a `notEqual` method. My previous example becomes as follows:

```
where(DSL.field(DSL.field("field_a", Integer.class).isNotNull()).notEqual(DSL.field(DSL.field("field_b", Integer.class).isNull()))))
```

I don't think it's the most elegant, but definitely more elegant than using the DNF.